# Why is my clojurescript macro not working

Tags: clojure, macros, lisp, clojurescript, leiningen

I need `when-not-empty-let` macro similar to `clojure/core`'s [`when-let`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/when-let). So, I've just added `not-empty` call to [`when-let` macro from clojure's source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1853):

```
(defmacro when-not-empty-let
  "bindings => binding-form test
  When test is not empty, evaluates body with binding-form bound to the value of test"
  [bindings & body]
  (.log js/console "check")
  (let [form (first bindings) tst (second bindings)]
    `(let [temp# ~tst]
       (when (not-empty temp#)
         (let [~form temp#]
           ~@body)))))
```

(also replaced `(bindings 0)` with `(first bindings)` as it didn't compile otherwise)

I use it in a following way:

```
(defn something
  []
  (when-not-empty-let [foo ["foo"]]
    (.log js/console foo)))

(something)
```

I'm getting following output:

> undefined
>
> check

What am I doing wrong?

---

Builded with Clojure v1.9.0, ClojureScript: v1.10.126, lein-cljsbuild: v1.1.7

Tested in Chrome v59.0.3071.115 under Ubuntu.

---

**UPD:** jsbin that reproduces issue (at least for me): https://jsbin.com/liluwer/1/edit?js,output

See output from question in browser's developer tool console.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, at least using Clojure. I doubt a difference in Cljs behavior would cause this though. Your output also doesn't seem to make sense. "check" should happen immediately, and undefined should happen *after* that. If you're getting nothing after "check" it would appear the `undefined` is unrelated, and you're actually getting no output at all. Running this in Clojure (after changing the prints to `println`, I get as outout `check [foo]` (with a newline between them).

Comment: The binding assignments can also be reduced down to `(let [[form tst] bindings]` using deconstruction. Not the problem here, but it's a lot nicer looking.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks for your participation, I've updated question with link to jsbin, pls check it out.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with the jsbin. "Output" just shows a pixel value, and "console" shows the expanded macro for some reason, but not the run code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That's the best fiddler I've found so far, unfortunately you should open browser dev tool to see actual logs (that's usually F12 / console section)

Comment: Sorry, but jsbin is just proving to be an exercise in frustration. It keeps just spitting out `(cljs.core/let [temp__1__auto__ nil] (cljs.core/when (cljs.core/not-empty temp__1__auto__) (cljs.core/let [nil temp__1__auto__])))`. I'll see if I can get cljs working in IntelliJ. Looking over the code though, it seems fine, and runs fine under clj.

Comment: @Carcigenicate my bad, I didn't know I supposed to add macros to `.clj` file instead of `.cljs`. Can't check it right now as I got issues with building but I think that's it

Comment: No, I mean I tested it using Clojure (clj) not Clojurescript (cljs). I actually don't know Clojurescript, but have worked with Clojure for a couple of years now. I'm assuming that if you're writing Cljs, any macros would need to be in a Cljs file.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I found the error, tried to test macro in the same namespace. Anyway, huge thanks for your participation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [ClojureScript docs](http://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/defmacro):

> There is a strict rule for when you can use defmacro -- you can only use it in what we call a macro namespace, effectively forcing you to separate your compile time and runtime code.

The error is I tried to test the macro in the same namespace.